# I'm trying to deploy this code for 2 days but always getting an: IndexError: list index out of range. Im doing the Patrick Collins. How to solve it?

Tags: solidity, python

```py
from brownie import FundMe 
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account 
    
#the erro is on this file, I've testing in other file and it worked normally
    
def fund():  
  fund_me = FundMe[-1]  
  account = get_account()
  entrance_fee = fund_me.getEntranceFee()
    
def main():
  fund()
```

Comment: Which line of code show this error? Is it caused by the functions you called in `get_account` or `getEntranceFee`

Answer (score 0):

The getEntranceFee was incorrect.  this is the correct code.

```
function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {

    // minimumUSD
    uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
    uint256 price = getPrice();
    uint256 precision = 1 * 10**18;
    // return (minimumUSD * precision) / price;
    // We fixed a rounding error found in the video by adding one!
    return ((minimumUSD * precision) / price) + 1;
}
```